# R: How to make bar chart across several columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart that visualizes the values across several columns and I am a bit lost on how to do it.

My columns are:

```
Theme_1 <- c(0,15023,15614,0,0,145618,204656,2065,11564,0)
Theme_2 <- c(0,10264,0,10485,0,15460,20000,2000,0,15640)
Theme_3 <- c(2564,26904,0,16048,0,1980,0,10564,1894,19614)
Theme_4 <- c(0,0,0,10189,1105,1361,1780,20458,2000,0)
```

I have tried the following

1. ```
   BNG_final %>%
          ggplot(aes(Theme_1, Theme_2, Theme_3, Theme_4)) + 
          geom_histogram()
   ```

Attempt 1- This did not work - as the themes are not lined up on the x-axis

2. (NB. I have 19 observations)

   ```
   Theme_df <- data.frame(Q=1:19, CP=c(BNG_final$Theme_1), 
                       CRG=c(BNG_final$Theme_2), 
                       Edu = c(BNG_final$Theme_3), 
                       Health = c(BNG_final$Theme_4))                         


   Theme_graph_1 <- Theme_df %>%
     gather(key = "Themes", value = "Level")

   ggplot(data = Theme_graph_1, aes(x = Themes))+
     geom_bar() + 
     ggtitle("Thematic spread")
   ```

Attempt 2- I did get the right set up, but the themes are visualized as 4 dark columns and does not portray the accumulated values for each theme.

I want a bar for each theme, which accumulates the total value.

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to calculate the sums beforehand using `group_by` and `summarise`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(Theme_1, Theme_2, Theme_3, Theme_4) %>% 
  gather(k, v) %>% 
  group_by(k) %>% 
  summarise(Sum=sum(v)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(k, Sum, fill=k)) + 
   geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Or simply use

```
tibble(Theme_1, Theme_2, Theme_3, Theme_4) %>% 
  gather(k, v) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(k, v, fill=k)) + 
   stat_summary(fun.y="sum", geom="bar")
```

Comment: Thnak you! That's great, but how do you then combine all columns that are Theme 1, Theme 2 etc. So you in the end only have 4 columns with the accumulated values?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! :-D

Comment: @BloopFloopy if you are happy with the answer consider to accept it.